# pdf resize in browser before opening

Tags: .net, asp.net, pdf

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
string FilePath = Server.MapPath("reliance.pdf");
 Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
        Response.End();
```

How can we resize the pdf file before it gets open in browser....can you tell me? thanks

Comment: This may be beside the point totally... but I hate it when a document or web page resizes my app's window! Don't do it, please. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this, you can customise a lot with some parameters:

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf